# Change selected text in input field or texarea

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

According to the [specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)  `document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'Pasted text')` inserts the given plain text at the insertion point (deletes selection).

This does work in Chromium and Opera for textarea and input field, but  doesn't work in Firefox, see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2wo8tk4t/4/).

Any way to make it work in Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `contentEditable="true"` attribute.

https://jsfiddle.net/99fysok7/4/

There are some quirks though. It seems this does not work well with input fields on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `selectionStart` en `selectionEnd` and replace the selected text as follows:

```
el=document.activeElement;
el.value=el.value.substring(0,el.selectionStart)+
"Pasted Text"
+el.value.substring(el.selectionEnd);
```